# Why are correlation functions so important in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Apparently correlation functions capture all the important information about a quantum field theory. Nonetheless, I have never been given a reason of why this should be the case. So, does anybody have any insight about why vacuum expectation values of operators should be so important?

Answer (score 14):

1. From a practical point of view, the correlation functions are important because they are the quantities you need to determine to compute the scattering amplitudes by e.g. the LSZ reduction formula.
2. From an axiomatic point of view, the correlation functions are important because the Wightman reconstruction theorem says that, under certain assumptions, a Wightman QFT is *fixed* by its values for the n-point function, i.e. giving the complete set of n-point functions is equivalent to giving the actual fields.

Comment: what do you precisely mean by "giving the actual fields"?

Comment: @Scardenalli: A Wightman field is an operator-valued distribution on spacetime. You never really want to specify that explicitly, so it's nice to know that if two theories have the same n-point functions, they are "the same theory" (up to a certain kind of isomorphism), that is, if you specify a prescription for computing the n-point functions, that's the same as actually defining the operator-valued distribution.

Comment: Why do we care about scattering amplitudes so much?

Answer (score 6):

Scattering amplitudes, transition probability, propagators and vertex amplitudes can be reduced to sum of products of correlations functions altogether (see the [LSZ reduction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_reduction_formula), for example).